# Spring 1.4.0 release hibernate naming strategy will add underscore(_) to table and column names

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data

I have upgraded my spring version from 1.3.6 to 1.4.0 and now when I try to access my controller and see the log it always fetches for table with _ added to camel case conversion.
I am using EJB3NamingStrategy as before but that is not helpful here.
Here is how my application.yml looks

```
 spring:
   jpa:
    hibernate:
      naming:
        strategy: org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy
```

Answer (score 2):

I used this and it worked.

spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl